# May I use CDN for whole website (PHP, Apache, MySQL) or just for images and CSS, JS files?

Tags: hosting, cdn, cloud-hosting, uptime, dedicated-hosting

May I use CDN for whole website (PHP, Apache, MySQL) or just for images and CSS, JS files?

What's the best choice > cloud-hosting or dedicated-hosting? Does CDN has that support?

Witch hosting you suggest me the best - the fastest, stablest 100% uptime, CDN, not expensive at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDN hosting is purely for static content only - it is never advised to host a dynamic application on CDN.

CDN is a content delivery network - your hosting company has edge servers on various locations across the globe. **Job of these edge servers is to cache your content** and deliver to your clients. If edge server doesn't have cached your content, **they pull these content from the source server** and deliver to your visitor. If they have cached copy, they deliver that immediately. This cache is usually refreshed every 12 hours - it varies host by host.

Since edge servers deliver cached copy, **it is never advised to host dynamic websites** on CDN Hosting.

Question:

> What's the best choice? cloud-hosting or dedicated-hosting? Does CDN
>   has that support?

Answer:

Cloud hosting is superior by infrastructure. It has redundant array of disk drives and processors. You will enjoy almost 100% uptime on Cloud hosting.

Question:

> Witch hosting you suggest me the best - the fastest, stablest 100%
>   uptime, CDN, not expensive at all?

Answer: From my professional experience, **CDN hosting is the fastest**, **Cloud hosting is stable and 100% uptime** and **VPS Hosting is not expensive**. If you want to make a choice of of these three, **Cloud hosting is stable and cost-effective**.

Comment: From my experience, the best pick is [Rackspace Cloud Servers](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/compare/) and 
[CloudFlare CDN](http://www.cloudflare.com).

Answer (score 0):

From the way the question was phrased, I think managed hosting would be most appropriate for your application.

It is fairly unlikely that you will run into any performance issues that are not self-inflicted (say, by writing suboptimal database queries, performing database processing in the frontend etc) unless you have a significant advertising budget and a mass market application, in which case you should also have a mid-sized IT department that can roll a custom solution.

Weighing cost and reliability against each other can be left to the accountants, for the most part.